# How do Google Analytics and products like it send data from the client's browser to their backend securely?

Tags: javascript, api, security

So let's say I have a website where I sell various products but I do not have access to the backend code. I can put Javascript on the front end, though, and I want to create my own product browsing tracking system. Something really simple like just capturing that a product page was loaded and some details about it. I want to send the data to an API I wrote, and record the info into a table, like so:

```
window.onload = function captureProduct() {
    let productId = document.getElementById('productId')
    let productName = document.getElementById('productName')
    let pageUrl = window.location.href;

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var raw = JSON.stringify({
        "ProductId": productId,
        "Name": productName,
        "PageUrl": pageUrl
    });

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: raw
    };

    fetch("https://api.website.com/product", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

That all works fine. The API receives the data and writes it to a table. However, while doing this, I realized I just can open up the dev console on my browser and make API calls while on the site with whatever data I want. I can fake the URLs, product ids and names by simply putting in hardcoded values, like this:

```
    var raw = JSON.stringify({
        "ProductId": "fake id",
        "Name": "hello",
        "PageUrl": "https://not-my-site.com"
    });

    ...

    fetch("https://api.website.com/product", raw)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Because this API call is happening client side, my understanding is no matter what I do the client will see everything so I cannot use the "standard" auth methods without exposing secrets or keys. So my question is: how do companies like Google or SalesForce track this kind of stuff without leaving huge holes in their applications? What is stopping people from going on websites, figuring out this have Google analytics on their site and doing stuff like this in the web browser:

```
gtag('event', 'click', {
    event_category: 'fake data',
    event_label: 'testttt',
    event_value: '0',
    transport: 'beacon'
});
```

and putting garbage into their data? How do you secure something like this?

Comment: When you configure Google Analytics, you tell it your domains. If someone at another site tries to send GA with your tracking ID, they'll ignore it because it comes from the wrong domain.

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't stop someone from using the dev console while on that site from sending their own data. I configured CORS on my API and was still able to send requests via the dev console while on the site. I checked the headers of the request and it was my whitelisted domain. Unless I did something wrong

Comment: I think they just don't care about the occasional fake. They're collecting statistics, and a small percentage error is not significant.